# Save new Entity with relations on existed Entity (Symfony/Doctrine2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create new Entity SlideTranslation, and assign existed slide.
But every time entity had created without id of Slide. I can create SlideTranslation and than assign Slide to it, but it seems bad solution for me.

```
$slide = $em->getRepository('Model:Slide')->find($id);

if(isset($slide)) {
    try {
        $slideTranslation = new SlideTranslation();
        $slideTranslation->setTranstable($slide);
        $slideTranslation->setLocale('uk');
        $slideTranslation->setAltText('Alt text');
        $em->persist($slideTranslation);
        $em->flush();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Relations.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model\Entity\Slide", inversedBy="tranlations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="translatable_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $transtable;
```

I have tried method with **getReference**, but no result. Maybe  I am breaking some patterns or principles and It's not possible in Doctrine2.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to probably do it in the other way around

```
$slide = $em->getRepository('Model:Slide')->find($id);

$slideTranslation = new SlideTranslation();
$slideTranslation->setLocale('uk');
$slideTranslation->setAltText('Alt text');

$slide->addTranslation($slideTranslation);

$em->flush();
```

Then add cascade to the Slide entity, and you don't even need to persist the entity Translation

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Model\Entity\SlideTranslation", mappedBy="transtable", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $translations;
```

Comment: What does method "addTranslation"?

Comment: You should have a double relation between the entity Slide and SlideTranslation, and Slide should have the methods addTranslation, removeTranslation, getTranslations and setTranslations

Comment: What are you using for the translations? This https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/translatable.md ?

Comment: I have both relations. Can you write here addTranslation method as you see it. Cause, I know about getters and setters, hav to remove and add, but never face addSomething method in entity. Maybe, it;s like add into array collection and doctrine do the hole thing. I am not using any extension, have written mine.

Comment: Check this code https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/issues/244#issuecomment-47432977, I think you should add that extension, doing it again is reinventing the wheel IMO

Comment: I am absolutely agree with you about the wheel. I have used tranlatable extension from Knp, but it was not compatible with my needs, so I took principles from there and created my own. I have already done it, Just looking for way to code better, without multiple requests into DB.